# Can I retrain the model with samples who have low OOB error?

Tags: matlab, random-forest, non-linear-regression

I trained a RF regression model for blood pressure estimation from PPG signal and tested it with Out-Of-Bag (OOB) error.
I find that for several samples from my dataset (about 10% of dataset) the OOB prediction is poor.
Is it possible to separate the samples with poor OOB prediction and retrain the model with samples that have good OOB prediction?
Is this a good idea for improving the model accuracy?
Thanks a lot